# Images in Google Docs Blurrying When Viewed In Mobile Browser

Tags: google-docs, iphone, safari

Images embedded in Google Docs look great when viewed on a Desktop.

but when viewed in iPhone Safari browser, they're all blurry.

would make sense if it was the other way around. is there anything i can do to guarantee they look in mobile as good as they do on desktop?

Comment: Is your phone set to "Low Data Mode"?

Comment: no it is not in low data mode

Comment: well this is NOT a duplicate question but it is along the same lines as my other question that's linked to in the dupe box above. i asked separately because i didn't know it would have the same answer... but it does.

Comment: There is no problem at all to publicate questions that later be marked as duplicate of others... duplicate are like sign posts showing the path to the answer :)